# Extend DateTime and DateTimeImmutable in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, oop, extend

I have a bunch of little procedural functions that manipulate `DateTime` in various ways, and it occurs to me that it might be easier to work with if I extend the `DateTime` class and turn these functions into methods of the class.

Okay, so easy peasy I can just do:

```
namespace My\Project;

class DateTime extends \DateTime {
    ... various new methods etc...
}
```

BUT... I also work with `DateTimeImmutable` objects, and would also want these additions in that class.

Is there some way to extend *both* of those classes to include my new functionality *without repeating code*?  (Yes I know I can copy/paste the new methods into both new classes.  Trying to be DRY here.)

Doesn't PHP have some way to "sideload" code into a class?  Or a way to extend `DateTimeInterface` but also include the code specific to `DateTime` and `DateTimeImmutable`?

Is it bad practice to extend common classes like this?  (Is it going to bite me in the butt down the road?)

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice. There's actually a really good library called [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/) that extends DateTime with a lot of functionality. You can extend both classes with the functions you need, and call those classes instead of the originals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create the two classes, each of those extending either `DateTime` or `DateTimeImmutable`, and a trait with all your "new methods, etc" which you can `use` directly in both of them.

```php
trait Convenient {
    public function echo() : void {
        echo "bar\n";
    }
}

class A extends \DateTime  {
    use Convenient;
}

class B extends \DateTimeImmutable {
    use Convenient;
}
```

Regarding "best practice", that's a matter of opinion; but it's hard to imagine anyone objecting to extending base classes. It's done all the time for a lot of valid reasons. Ideally client scripts should be targeting the interfaces, not the classes anyway.

There are couple of well known and widely use libraries, like [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) or [Chronos](https://github.com/cakephp/chronos) that extend on the base date time objects. You may want to check those out before reinventing them.

Comment: Since posting this question, I have indeed seen people arguing that you should never extend something you don't control.  That you should only extend your own classes.  That said, Carbon is a pretty good example of doing it successfully